# Adding text to a cell using VBA WITHOUT deleting what was already in the cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to change what is in a cell after a macro populates it with data. For instance, my macro will place 750 in the cell. I need to then place a "T" in the cell, after the 750, without deleting the 750. The 750 will change each time I use the macro, so I can't just use `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "750 T"`

It will always be a number with a "T" added, although its fine if it's formatted as text.

Comment: What about `ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & " T"`

Comment: Your question isn't that clear and please post a sample of your code. But, you can try putting the macro populated data in a *container* then use that container variable to output the editted version with the "T".

Comment: Why don't you have your macro add the T ?

Comment: What's the code you're using? You could store the value to a variable and then concatenate the " T"

Comment: Do you also need to do something mathematical with the "750"? Like, is 750 pulled in as a variable and added to / subtracted from? Consider just creating a custom number format, which adds "T" to the end of a number.

Comment: @padawan0007 that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Also, I apologize if the question wasn't as clear as it could have been.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to keep what's there and add a T, so here is how:

```
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & " T"
```

You can change ActiveCell to whatever you want.

Completely plagiarized from @padawan0007, although the answer was obvious.

Also I have to ask if you are using ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 for a particular reason? You should use .Value instead if you're not inserting an actual formula.

Comment: I'm very new to programming and the obvious answer is not always so obvious for me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "750 T"` seems like it would be the resulting line of code after recording a macro while manually typing `750 T` into a cell.  I'd be willing to bet that's why he used `.FormulaR1C1` instead of `.Value`

Comment: You would be right @padawa0007. I recorded what I could of a macro, and now I'm going back through it and changing the parts that I need to. Not the best or cleanest method, but I don't have much choice.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that.  I do it a ton, and it's a great way to learn.  But it does leave some telltale signs, though, like `.Select`, `.Activate`, and my personal favorites, `.ScrollRow` and `.ScrollColumn`

Answer (score 5):

A more flexible approach is to use custom format for such arbitrary suffixes. For example,

```
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "#,##0 T;-#,##0 T"
```

will put the T as you want for **750 T** without the overhead of re-running macros when the number 750 changes. You can copy, paste, sort, and perform the usual operations on such cell values without affecting the T suffix.

Comment: Agree with this - either apply the format through the VBA macro, or if it's a specific set of cells you could even just apply the formatting standard in Excel manually. Either way, this will be more useful to you if you want the base number to be there. On the other hand, if you need to use the T in your operations (ie: say you want to check whether "250 T" matches any of your cells), you will need to add the " T" into the cell as suggested in another answer.

Comment: This way is better.  I was being lazy.